# Angular & SEO (static pages)

Tags: angularjs, seo

I am going to be using Angular for a slew of webapps, and I have found a few articles (on here as well as other sites) about using Phantom.JS to render static pages to serve to bots.

There is some push back among the devs I am working with that using Phantom.js will cause unnecessary tax on the server and using a batch job to akamize the generated pages say once per week would be too many moving parts.

So essentially I am here to ask what others are doing for solutions to dynamically generated content via ajax and static pages for SEO.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a good answer for you as I haven't implemented a solution myself yet.  In fact just read up a bit on phantom.js and it seems like a good solution. Perhaps bots can be addressed separately  http://www.yottaa.com/blog/bid/215372/The-Real-Story-of-Bot-Traffic-And-How-to-Prevent-it-from-Killing-Performance Alternatively you could potentially limit bots based on the user agent http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum39/4278.htm

Comment: "closed as not constructive" ... then what is the purpose of stackoverflow??

Comment: "but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." ... that sounds excellent ..